# Arch - top - cached memory size is huge

Tags: memory

The orange (cached memory) bar is huge compared to the red one -
[image]

Does it mean I can't use this memory? The xfce4 Task Manager reports a 25% memory usage. What exactly does 'cached memory' mean?

Answer (score 0):

The Linux kernel will aggressivly use RAM to cache block I/O (i.e. disk requests). RAM is no good after all, if it's not used.

When an application needs RAM, the kernel will just drop clean caches to make it available with very low latency

In fact just think "This part of RAM is available for your applications, but while you don't need it, we might just as well make it usefull in the meantime"